# Scrabble word finder with wildcards

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

I’ve got a problem and it seems some before me have had similar problems but I haven’t been able to find a working solution for me.

I’m currently building a mobile web application using C#, MySQL, HTML5 and Javascript. The application will be used to help users to find possible words to play while playing games like Scrabble.

The problem I’ve got:
How do I get the right words from a MySQL database containing a dictionary from user letter input?

More details:
- Users can input any number of letters and also use wildcards (representing any letter) .
- If the user inputs “TEST” the result can’t contain words with more than 1 E and S and words with more than 2 T, a result with “TESTER” in it would be bad.
- The result can’t contain words with more letters than inputted.

UPDATE: Seems Trie is the solution to my problem as suggested by Eric Lippert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418910/scrabble-word-finder-with-wildcards/7419003#7419003).
Problem is I'm a beginner with both C# and MySQL, so here are some follow up questions:

1. How do I create a Trie from my MySQL dictionary? (400k+ words)
2. How do I store the Trie for quick and future access?
3. How do I access the Trie and extract words from it with C#?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: hi this is equivalent to finding all permutations of some letters in a dictionary (and this is *hard*) but you if you search for permutation here you will find a lot algorithms to get you all permutations fo your letters - then you *only* have to find the right subset .... (BTW: the wildcards make this even worse)

Comment: Part 42 of why every CS student should take a data structures course.

Comment: You might consider creating some new questions for your update; you're likely to get more attention to a new question. Also: I have been planning on doing a blog article on how to use a trie to solve your problem for some time now; I've just never gotten around to doing so. If I ever do post that article I'll come back here and update this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How do I get the right words from a MySQL database containing a dictionary from user letter input?

You don't. A relational database table is not a suitable data structure for solving this problem as efficiently as you need to.

What you do instead is you build a **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** data structure out of the dictionary (or, if you're really buff, you build a **[dawg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)** -- a directed acyclic word graph -- which is a sort of compressed trie.)

Once you have a trie/dawg it becomes very inexpensive to test *every* word in the dictionary against a given rack, because you can "prune out" whole huge branches of the dictionary that the rack cannot possibly match.

Let's look at a small example. Suppose you have the dictionary "OP, OPS, OPT, OPTS, POT, POTS, SOP, SOPS, STOP, STOPS"  From that you build this trie: (Nodes with a $ are those that are marked as "word can end here".

```
           ^root^
           /  |  \
         O    P    S
         |    |   / \
         P$   O  O   T   
        / \   |  |   |
       T$  S$ T$ P$  O
       |      |  |   |
       S$     S$ S$  P$
                     |
                     S$
```

and you have the rack "OPS" -- what do you do?

First you say "can I go down the O branch?"  Yes, you can. So now the problem is matching "PS" against the O branch. Can you go down the P subbranch?  Yes. Does it have an end-of-word marker? Yes, so OP is a match. Now the problem is matching "S" against the OP branch. Can you go down the T branch? No. Can you go down the S branch? Yes. Now you have the empty rack and you have to match it against the OPS branch. Does it have an end-of-word marker? Yes! So OPS matches also. Now backtrack up to the root.

Can you go down the P branch? Yes. Now the problem is to match OS against the P branch. Go down the PO branch and match S -- that fails. Backtrack to the root.

And again, you see how this goes. Eventually we go down the SOP branch and find an end-of-word on SOP, so "SOP" matches this rack. We don't go down the ST branch because we don't have a T.

We've tried every possible word in the dictionary and discovered that OP, OPS and SOP all match. But we never had to investigate OPTS, POTS, STOP or STOPS because we didn't have a T.

You see how this data structure makes it very efficient? Once you have determined that you do not have the letters on the rack to make the *beginning* of a word, you don't have to investigate *any* dictionary words that start with that beginning. If you have PO but no T, you don't have to investigate POTSHERD or POTATO or POTASH or POTLATCH or POTABLE; all those expensive and fruitless searches go away very quickly.

Adapting the system to deal with "wild" tiles is pretty straightforward; if you have OPS?, then just run the search algorithm 26 times, on OPSA, OPSB, OPSC... It should be fast enough that doing it 26 times is cheap (or doing it 26 x 26 times if you have two blanks.)

This is the basic algorithm that professional Scrabble AI programs use, though of course they also have to deal with things like board position, rack management and so on, which complicate the algorithms somewhat. This simple version of the algorithm will be plenty fast enough to generate all the possible words on a rack.

Don't forget that of course you only have to compute the trie/dawg *once* if the dictionary is not changing over time. It can be time-consuming to build the trie out of the dictionary, so you might want to do so *once* and then figure out some way to store the trie on disk in a form that is amenable to rebuilding it quickly from disk.

You can optimize the memory usage by building a DAWG out of the trie. Notice how there is a lot of repetition because in English, lots of words *end* the same, just as lots of words *begin* the same. The trie does a great job of sharing nodes at the beginning but a lousy job of sharing them at the end. You can notice for example that the "S$ with no children" pattern is extremely common, and turn the trie into:

```
           ^root^
          / |  \
        O   P    S
        |   |   / \
        P$  O  O   T   
       /  \ |  |   |
      T$  | T$ P$  O
      |    \ | |   |
       \    \| /   P$
        \    |/    |
         \   |    /
          \  |   /  
           \ |  /
            \| /  
             |/
             |       
             S$
```

Saving a whole pile of nodes. And then you might notice that two words now end in O-P$-S$, and two words end in T$-S$, so you can compress it further to:

```
           ^root^
           / | \
          O  P  S
          |  | / \
          P$ O \  T   
         /  \|  \ |
         |   |   \|
         |   |    O
         |   T$   |
          \  |    P$
           \ |   /
            \|  /  
             | /
             |/   
             S$
```

And now we have the minimal DAWG for this dictionary.

Further reading:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=42420

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/dawg1

http://www.gtoal.com/wordgames/scrabble.html

Comment: and if you to sort the order of this depth-first-search to match the languagues alphabet-distribution you can get to results even quicker

Comment: As to the problem of how to store the tries on disk:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=VS.100).aspx
.nets loverly  XML serialisation is your friend here.

Comment: If you build a trie of words sorted alphabetically though, it could be a lot quicker, can't it? In your example, the trie would have OP, OPS, OPST, OPSS, OPSST, each word-end pointer pointing to all its anagrams. Then you'd have to go over the trie once for each subset of the original string. If I'm not mistaken, that would make it O(2^n) where n is the number of letters in the rack - not a problem for a standard rack of 7, even with gigantic dictionaries.

Comment: @configurator: That's a pretty standard solution, and one of the other answers to this question proposes it. In practice it turns out to be less efficient when actually building Scrabble AIs. Incidentally, this was one of the questions I was asked when I first interviewed for a full-time position at Microsoft; I found your proposed solution but not the trie solution.

Comment: Does that mean I can now get a job there without doing the interview because I already passed? :P

Comment: @configurator: You'll note that I did not say whether that team extended me an offer or not. They did not. (Though it was a moot point, as the team was disbanded a few weeks later.) I was no-hired by all the teams that interviewed me at Microsoft; I was extended an offer by the VB team on the basis of my internships, not on the basis of my interviews.

Comment: Damn, I was this close to getting in!

Comment: @Eric: What do you mean by no-hired? Do you mean "don't hire"? Or "not hired"? Just curious because I haven't seen that phrase before and it's highly unlikely that it's a typo.

Comment: @Joan: I mean the interviewer sent an email to the hiring manager where the title of the email was NO HIRE, meaning "do not extend an offer to this guy". Apparently I didn't interview well that day, though an interesting mitigating factor was that there was a snow storm that day and none of the people who were originally supposed to interview me showed up. Some of the interviewers seemed slightly unprepared.

Comment: Thanks Eric for explaining. Really bizarre indeed. Strange how some companies do these things. I imagine it's only the bigger companies, but I never been involved in hiring people. Glad they did hire you though, couldn't imagine what state C# would be in without your contributions.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm confused - but how is your algorithm handles OP's  "no more than 2 T characters requirement" for example?

Comment: @Dannyboy: Suppose the user inputs `ESTT`.  You have your trie.  You ask "can I go down the A branch?" No.  "Can I go down the B branch?" no. ... "Can I go down the E branch?" Yes.  Now on the E branch we remove "E" and now have the problem "STT". Solve that problem. Now is it clear? When you go down a branch you remove the item you hit from the rack of available letters and start over.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you! I get it now - it totally works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve the problem (assuming of course that you have control of the DB, and can modify tables/add tables, or even control the original load of the DB).

My solution would use 2 tables -> one table would just be a list of every possible letter combination from your dictionary with the component letters sorted alphabetically. (IE TEST would be ESTT, TESTER would be ERSTT, DAD would be ADD).

The second table would have every word and a reference to the key for table one.

Table One - LetterInWord

```
Index Letters
1     ESTT
2     ESTTER
3     EST
4     ADD
5     APST
```

In table one, you insert the words letters in alphabetical order - test becomes estt

Table Two - Words

```
Index LetterInWordIndex  Word
1     1                  TEST
2     2                  TESTER
3     3                  SET
4     4                  ADD
5     4                  DAD
6     5                  SPAT
7     5                  PAST
```

In table 2 you insert the word with  appropriate word and index reference.

This will be a one to many relationship -> One entry in LetterInWord table could have multiple entries in Words table

Non-wild card look up:
Say my input letters are SETT
Sort them alphabetically.

Then in the look up, you select all "Letters" from LetterInWord where Letters = value and join on table Words - your output in one query is a list of all words that only contain those letters

Now for wild cards:
Say my input letters are EST*
Remember the length - 4
Strip out the wildcards - you get EST (make sure you sort this alphabetically)
Now look for all cases where Letters contains EST and Letters Length <= 4 joined on Words table

That would return TEST, REST, SET, etc

I'm not sure if that is the most efficient method, but it works.  I have used it in the past to do word look ups from dictionaries, and it has reasonable performance with minimal complexity.

Comment: This is a pretty typical algorithm for this problem. It performs extremely well when the problem is "given a rack of size n, find all the n-letter words which exactly match the rack".  Unfortunately your algorithm performs poorly when asked "given a rack of size n, find all of the n-or-fewer-letter words which match the rack".  Since that is the problem actually faced by the original poster, I wouldn't recommend this algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

This will be very difficult to do if all you have is the dictionary.  If you have the ability to make a new table or new columns, I would :

Create a table with a column for the word, plus 26 columns (one for each letter)
Run a stored proc/backend process that counts the occurences of each letter in a word, and puts them into the appropriate column.

Then (ignoring wildcards) you can do

Select word from dictionary where tcount <=2 and ecount <=1 and scount <=1

for wildcards you could do and length <= number_of_letters

Actually always use the length clause, because you will then be able to index on it to improve performance.

Anything else is going to be exceptionally slow during the query