# Data structure to store Turkish words, which are roots with many suffixes, which allows prefix text searching?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

I am wondering how to implement this for any [agglutinative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutinative_language), and Turkish is an example agglutinative language so we can focus on that. This basically means words are formed from a base/root and many suffixes are appended. This leads to [really long words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_Turkish) (most of which are never spoken or are extremely rare, but they are technically still *possible*), such as `muvaffakiyetsizleştiricileştiriveremeyebileceklerimizdenmişsinizcesine` which is 70 letters in Turkish. That word means basically a full sentence, "as though you are from those whom we may not be able to easily make into a maker of unsuccessful ones".

So let's say Turkish has 10,000 "base" or "root" words, and 1,000 suffixes, and we can add up to 10 suffixes. I don't know [how to estimate the rough number of nodes this will be in a trie](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162755/how-to-estimate-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-trie-based-on-a-dictionary-of-words) yet, but it seems like it would be a lot. Then I am imagining [how to store a trie in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353322/what-is-the-most-optimal-way-to-store-a-trie-for-typeahead-suggestions-in-distri/72516273#72516273), because it seems this kind of trie will be too large to store in memory (correct me if I'm wrong), and it seems completely impractical to do this for Turkish, according to that answer:

> Key-value store: A trie can be represented in a hash table form [4] by applying the following logic:
> • Every prefix in the trie is mapped to a key in a hash table.
> • Data on each trie node is mapped to a value in a hash table.

If every prefix was mapped to a key in the relational database table, there would be a possibly practically infinite number of rows (assume 70 character max words, and a 30 character alphabet, that seems like 30^70 combinations, or 2.5x10^103 values, but it would be smaller than that, still too many to list explicitly).

So how would you store these "possible turkish words" to allow for fast querying? What sort of data structures and/or database systems would you use, given it is impractical to serialize each prefix as a key in a hash table? Basically, how would you allow for prefix text searching of *possible* Turkish words, some of which may never have been written or said explicitly, but are still valid words?

Comment: The number of possibilities is pretty easy to compute. From your numbers: 1e4*(1e3^10) = 1e34 at the upper end. If your interested in possible words regardless of whether they're real or not, you don't have to store the sequences, just the lists of fragments, which makes storage a lot easier. You don't really search so much as assemble the word as needed. For any prefix, you assemble enough pieces to match the prefix and just assume the rest is every combination to the length that would fill it in.