# Regex matching with wildcard and where each character in expression can only be used once

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help to write a Regex for character matching. The scenario is that I have a text file with about 300 000 lines, with one word on each line. I need to find the words that match a certain set of characters.

Think of Scrabble as a very similar example, where a user has a set of characters, say for example **P E S** plus a **wildcard** character that can match any character (but only once).

If the text file contains the following words:

- **PIE**
- **PIES**
- **PEES**
- PASS
- PLEASE

...only the words in bold should be matched, as each of the user's characters, including the wildcard, can only be used maximum once in matching.

Is there a way to write a regex expression for this?

I have started with...:

> \b[P,E,S]\b

...but don't know how I should express that:

1. Each character (P, E, S) can only be used once
2. Any character (the wildcard) can also be used once

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if I need to clarify the problem.

// Peter

Comment: So the wildcard character can occur anywhere in the word, yes?

Comment: What regular expression engine/version are you using?

Comment: This "class" of problems is resolved with trie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418910/scrabble-word-finder-with-wildcards here Lippert explains how to solve it. Regexes aren't the final wildcard to all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very easy with regex (if at all possible).
Much simpler would be something like this:

```
List<char> set = new List<char>("PES");

string s = "PIES";

bool matches = s.Count(ch => !set.Remove(ch)) < 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Impossible is nothing :

You can do this with regexes using lookahaeds :

```
(?=^.+$)(?=^[^P]*?P?[^P]*?$)(?=^[^E]*?E?[^E]*?$)(?=^[^S]*?S?[^S]*?$)
```

Basically if you break it down there are five components :

First lookahead :

```
(?=^.+$)
```

Checks if length is >= 1

Then the three parts :

```
(?=^[^P]*?P?[^P]*?$)
```

for E and S respectively check if a maximum of 1 of these characters exist.

The above simply tells to check the whole string for a single occurrence of P. If more than one P is found the regex fails. Same is applied to the following two lookaheads.

For the wildcard I have to think a smart way to do it :)..

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems to me that the words can be longer than 4 characters in the actual text file.

Comment: From what he has written, it seems that you don't need to use all the caracters, so `PI` and `PE` would both be valid

Comment: Well then maybe "" is also valid I guess :)

Comment: @Kobi Yeah I agree... I mean it's possible with regex but..quite complex and inefficient.